# Syntax error for if else statement in java, please correct

Tags: java, selenium

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class next {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver x = new FirefoxDriver();
                x.get("http://plus.com/");
                if (x.getTitle().contains("Plus – An Enterprise Messaging System"));
                {
                System.out.println("Pass");
                }
                else {System.out.println("Fail");}
                WebElement username = x.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/input"));
                username.sendKeys("rohit.@omtechnologies.com");
                WebElement pass = x.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/input"));
                pass.sendKeys("123456");
                WebElement login = x.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/button"));
                login.click();
    }
```

It shows red token at else line Syntax error on token else,delete this token. Please help i am very new to this.

Comment: You've got a semi-colon at the end of your `if` statement, making the body of the if statement empty. (This has nothing to do with Selenium.)

Comment: If you would have formatted the code and would have tried to create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would have been easier to answer and most likely, you would have found the syntax error on your own...

Answer (score 4):

```
            if (x.getTitle().contains("Plus – An Enterprise Messaging System"))
            {
            System.out.println("Pass");
            }
            else {
            System.out.println("Fail");
                  }
```

Remove the ; from if statement , try this.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `else` is dangling... Which means it doesn't have an associated `if`.

If you are wondering, the `if` condition ended as soon as you put a `;` in the statement.